# How does BoxWhiskerChart detect outliers?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, charts

`BoxWhiskerChart` can detect and show outliers:

```
SeedRandom[39]
BoxWhiskerChart[
  RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 100],
  "Outliers"
]
```

[image]

- What is the precise mathematical criterion used to decide if a point is an outlier?
- Can this criterion be tweaked?
- Is this criterion implemented by any documented built-in function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
iqrc = "IQRCoefficient" /. ChartElementData["BoxWhisker", "Options"];
```

> 1.5

```
fences = Quartiles[data][[{1, 3}]] + {-1, 1} iqrc InterquartileRange[data]

outliers = Select[Not @* Between[fences]] @ data
```

> {-3.0844, -3.4005}

which matches the vertical coordinates of outlier glyphs:

```
Cases[BoxWhiskerChart[data, "Outliers", PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"], 
 Inset[_, {_, a_}] :> a, All]
```

> {-3.0844, -3.4005}

Comment: Does `ChartElementData[..., "Options"]` appear anywhere within the documentation? I cannot find it (though I did find it in other SE answers).

Comment: @Szabolcs, afaik it does not appear in documentation. I think I bumped into it using the  spelunking trick: `ClearAttributes[ChartElementData, {Protected, ReadProtected}]; ?? ChartElementData`

Comment: I found one example in [BarChart >> Options >> ChartElementFunction >> last example](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarChart.html): `ChartElementData["GradientRectangle", "Options"]`

Answer (score 10):

It is actually in the help documentation as the last item. Outliers are 1.5 InterQuartileRanges (IQR) away from the nearest quartile and Far Outliers are 3 IQR distant.

[image: Documentation Snippet from Properties & Relations]

Comment: Indeed! It's under Properties and Relations. I found that, deleted the question, then undeleted when someone mentioned that they were just about to post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to tweak this option:

```mathematica
BoxWhiskerChart[data, "Outliers",
  ChartElementFunction -> 
    ChartElementDataFunction["BoxWhisker","IQRCoefficient" -> 3]
]
```